# Where can I download Netbeans 6.7.1?

Tags: netbeans

So, they updated Netbeans to 6.8 version, but I only want the 6.7.1 version. Any thoughts where I could find the older version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Netbeans6.7.1 with only Java environment try with [this one](http://filehippo.com/download_netbeans/6012/).

if not, you have [other choice](http://netbeans.org/downloads/6.7.1/index.html) from official website .. you can have choice of Release [Archives & Development Downloads](http://www.netbeans.info/downloads/dev.php).